# Data conversion to hexadecimal in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am facing issue in the following query. I want to convert a value to hexadecimal in SQL

```
select B.caption, convert(varbinary(8), cast(B.caption as decimal(10))) 
from TableA A 
inner join TableB B on A.name = B.name
```

I'm getting an error:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Sample Data:

```
8454266
```

Expected Result:

```
8454266, 0x0081007A
```

Comment: please show some sample data and the required result on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: table B  : 8454266   Output: 8454266, 0x0081007A

Answer (score 0):

first convert the string to integer then to varbinary

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(10) = '8454266';

SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(8), CONVERT(INT, @string));

-- result : 0x0081007A
```

to convert back to string, you need to reverse the process. [1] convert to INT, [2] convert to STRING

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(10) = '8454266',
        @varbin VARBINARY(8)

SELECT  @varbin = CONVERT(VARBINARY(8), CONVERT(INT, @string))

SELECT  @string, @varbin, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(INT, @varbin))
```

Comment: it is working fine. But when i am converting it back to varchar it is not giving any result. cast(Convert(VARBINARY(8),CONVERT(INT, @string))As varchar) )

Comment: For converting varbinary to string in hex please consult the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#binary-styles), specifically the `style` used.